# How to pause spider in Scrapy when blocked

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I am doing a Scrapy project that runs in an intranet server, I have to set a Proxy in order to connect to outside, so that I can't use the Proxy way (change IP) to prevent being banned.

### middlewares.py:

```
class SetProxy(object):
    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        request.meta['proxy'] = os.getenv('HTTP_PROXY')
```

---

My target website returns a 200 status response even when it blocks me, so I can only identify the content of response to check if I am blocked

### mySpider.py:

```
def parse(self, response):

    block_msg1 = "FOR SECURITY REASONS, THIS PAGE CAN NOT BE ACCESSED!"
    block_msg2 = "Overrun"

    # not be banned
    if str(response.body).find(block_msg1) == -1 and str(response.body).find(block_msg2) == -1:
        ......        
        yield item

    # get banned
    elif str(response.body).find(block_msg1) != -1 or str(response.body).find(block_msg2) != -1:

        # I want to pause Scrapy (stop sending requests but not stop pipelines' work) for a while here but I don't know how

        yield scrapy.Request(url=response.url, headers=sub_headers, callback=self.parse_sub)
```

---

How can I make Scrapy to stop sending requests for a while but not stop pipelines when I find being banned in the method parse_sub(), and recover after n minutes?

Comment: Umm... I think there's a `self.crawler.pause()`/`unpause()` available... but I can't remember if you need to run the crawl with a certain setting to keep job history...

Comment: Simple `time.sleep` will work

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options for your problem:

1. Change the [download delay](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#download-delay) and / or the [concurrent requests](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#concurrent-requests) in the settings
2. Use the scrapy [AutoThrottle extension](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/autothrottle.html)